# How to select a random sample of records from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table:

```
tweets
-----------------------
id  tweet         class
-----------------------
1   Foo bar baz!  2
2   Lorem ipsum   2
3   Foobar lorem  3
4   Activi set    1
5   Baz baz bar?  3
7   Dolor mez foo 3
8   Samet set bar 1
```

In reality, the table has 600,000 records, but as indicated in the example table, some `id`s have been deleted (so the highest `id` > 600,000).  `class` can be either `1`, `2` or `3`.

I need a **random selection** 1200 tweets, 400 of each `class`. Is this possible to do with one query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a finite number of possible values for `class` (3), then it is easily done with a set of `UNION` queries each having their own `ORDER BY RAND()` and `LIMIT 400`:

```
(SELECT id, tweet, class FROM tweets WHERE class = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 400)
UNION
(SELECT id, tweet, class FROM tweets WHERE class = 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 400)
UNION
(SELECT id, tweet, class FROM tweets WHERE class = 3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 400)
```

For the `ORDER BY` to be applied to each `UNION` group, the group must be enclosed in `()`.